# how to find the sum of all acolumn and row in 2d arry

Tags: c

how to find the sum of  all column and row in 2d 4x5 arry
I did this but it's not working

```
for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        summ = summ + arr[i][j];
    }
    printf("the sum of the amoda  is:%d\n", summ);
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize `summ` with `0`?

Comment: It would be helpful as @Shubham discusses to show to declaration / initialization of `summ`. If this does not solve the issue, it would also be good to explain what is not working exactly, what values do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very ambiguous. Do you want to find the sum of each column? If so, you should initialize `summ` to 0 for each of them:

```cpp
for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
{
    summ = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        summ = summ + arr[i][j];
    }
    printf("the sum of the column is: %d\n", summ);
}
```

If you want to find the sum of all numbers, then take that print out of the loop.